# Solidity extract a sub bytes32 from a source bytes32

Tags: solidity, contract-development, bytes32

I need to extract a sub-`bytes32` from a source `bytes32` so I wrote this `solidity` function:

```
function bytesOf(bytes32 source, uint start, uint count) private pure returns(bytes32) {
    bytes32 result;
    uint end = start + count;
    for (uint i = start; i < end; i++) {
        result[i - start] = source[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately that does not work and I get the error

```
TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.
    result[i - start] = source[i];
    ^---------------^
```

How would I do this?